# Subdomain apache problems

Tags: apache-2.2

So I'm trying to get apache to have multiple subdomains, but whenever I try and start apache I'm getting the following error:

```
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
```

I tried the following to see if anything was using the port:

```
root@xxx:/etc/apache2# netstat -ltnp | grep ':80'
root@xxx:/etc/apache2# lsof -i tcp:80
root@xxx:/etc/apache2#
```

Note that they both came back with nothing. I'm new to this and I'm assuming I'm doing something blatantly wrong. Here is my 'default' file from sites-available:

```
Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.xxx.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/xxx.com/site
    ErrorLog /srv/www/xxx.com/logs/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /srv/www/xxx.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName aaa.xxx.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/aaa/xxx.com/site
    ErrorLog /srv/aaa/xxx.com/logs/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /srv/aaa/xxx.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried looking through the apache docs and I looked through a few other forums, but it seems everything I found had netstat returning something and were generally for single sites without subdomains.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a debian-ish system. With that configuration, you don't put listen directives in your vhost files as they are already listed in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`. If this system is not a debian-ish system, just `grep -R listen /etc/apache2` and find where it's defined.

Comment: So that seemed to work, but I guess I'm lost as to why that would make a difference. Why would putting Listen in the vhosts file make a difference? Isn't apache just picking up each file and 'tailing' them one after another? I assumed any location would work...

Comment: If you have `Listen 80` twice in your config, apache will try to listen on port 80 twice. The second time will fail, as something is already listening on that port (apache itself).

Comment: Ahhhhhh gots it. So from the sounds of it you can only have 1 thing listening to a port at any given time?